# How can I programmatically start and interact with an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application. Its `HttpApplication` looks like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Do some sort of initialisation. Set the DependencyResolver.
    }
}
```

For an integration test, I want to programmatically start the application and use its `DependencyResolver` to interact with it. Accessing the `DependencyResolver` seems easy since I can just call `DependencyResolver.Current`. However, I haven't figured out how to get the application initialisation logic to run.

I've tried calling `new MvcApplication().Init()`, but this doesn't seem to trigger the `Application_Start` method call. I tried inheriting from `MvcApplication` and providing access to directly call `Application_Start`, but this failed with an exception from ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to test the framework here. You should only test your own code, if you need to simulate an the application object you should mock it.

Comment: @James, I'm trying to test that when the application is integrated with the framework, a specific outcome is achieved. I don't agree about only testing your own code; I think this it's just as valid to automatically test an application's integration as it is to have humans do so. What good is an application if its own code works fine but it doesn't integrate correctly with external systems? If a user can't even use it, it's useless.

Comment: @James, yes, mocking the framework is an *option*, but that doesn't mean I *should* do it. There are other valid options, too. Mocking wouldn't have caught the configuration-related integration bugs I ran into during manual testing the feature that this integration test should cover.

Comment: take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1651546/1246870 - does it help?

Comment: @Sam let me rephrase, *in my opinion* you shouldn't really be testing framework code. I stick by what I said, you should only test your code simply because it's what you have written, a framework like MVC would have been thoroughly tested before being released to the general public. "*Mocking wouldn't have caught the configuration-related integration bugs*" - that's because mocking isn't designed to catch anything, it's designed to give you an *expectation* of a particular object.

Comment: @Sam If you depend on a 3rd party it's reasonable to expect specific behaviour, if you need to 2nd guess and actually test that too then there is something clearly wrong.

Comment: @James, I agree that you should generally test your own code. However, expectations of third-party code and systems are not always true. Have you ever accidentally integrated incorrectly with one? I have. If I only test my own code, then what will detect such problems? Probably a human, which is perfectly valid, but I think doing an automated test to achieve the same is also valid.

Comment: @James, I agree that something is wrong if you aren't sure about the behaviour of a third-party library or system. The problem could be poor documentation, poor design, laziness, or something else. However, this is the real world, so the above are real and valid problems. In my case, I would say the problem was a combination of poor design and documentation and the fact that I have to work under heavy time pressure so I don't have time to thoroughly learn ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium WebDriver for integration testing MVC apps. You can progromatically interact with the application UI by coding actions for the web browser to take. Integration tests can then be ran from MSTest so that you can write assertions against the UI. Here is the documentation on Selenium http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Here is a code sample:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void runUITest()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //launches a Firefox window so you can observe the test run
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 7));                
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/yourWebApp"));
        //assert something
Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//fieldset[@id='YourControl']/div/div[2]/label/span/span")).Displayed);
        //find an element and click it
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("FormSubmitButton")).Click();           
    }
```

The Selenium WebDriver is available as a NuGet package.